# Escrever uma função dentro de determinados requisitos

Tags: c

Alguém pode me ajudar com o exercício abaixo?

1) Escreva uma função chamada atualizar, que não possui retorno (void), que terá quatro parâmetros de entrada: (a) um ponteiro/referência para uma estrutura do tipo DATA (ver abaixo), (b) um inteiro chamado dia, (c) um inteiro chamado mês, e (d) um inteiro chamado ano. Esta função deve atualizar os campos dia, mês e ano da estrutura referenciada pelo primeiro parâmetro da função.

```
/* Estrutura DATA */
typedef struct
{
int dia;
int mes;
int ano;
} DATA;
/* Assinatura da função atualizar */
void atualizar(DATA* pontData, int dia, int mes, int ano) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
struct Data {
    int dia;
    int mes;
    int ano;
}

void Atualizar(Data** data, int dia, int mes, int ano) {
    (*data)->dia = dia;
    (*data)->mes = mes;
    (*data)->ano = ano;
}
```

Seria isso? Se precisar de mais informações sobre o que está acontecendo, deixe um comentário que eu explico. Estou sem tempo agora, mas qualquer dúvida sobre o algoritmo por favor, me avise. Abraços!!